# How to apply splash screen with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, splash-screen

How to make proper `splashscreen` in jetpack compose?
It kind of works, but first it goes to `OnBoardingScreen` then it load data from `ViewModel` I have the same `viewmodel` for these screens and reload to start with `HomeScreen`.
I suppose it would be better to wait until it loads data from viewmodel then go with choosing the screen.
How to achieve that? Or what is better approach for splash screen with jetpack compose?

```
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = determineStartDestination(viewModel),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {

  private fun determineStartDestination(userModel: HomeViewModel): String {
        return if (userModel.homeState.value.emailFrom.isNotEmpty() && userModel.homeState.value.emailTo.isNotEmpty()) {
            OnHomeNav.getRoute()
        } else {
            OnBoardingScreenNav.getRoute()
        }
    }
```

EDIT: it does not work

```
Change in android manifest:
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.Starting"
MainActivity
        installSplashScreen().apply {
            setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                homeViewModel.homeState.value.emailFrom.isNotEmpty() && homeViewModel.homeState.value.emailTo.isNotEmpty()
            }
        }
      setContent { [...]
```

It launches this new splash screen, but logic with

```
setKeepOnScreenCondition { }
```

didn't help. I have the same action.
splash screen -> onboarding screen for 1 sec -> home screen

Ok I think I have found workaround but for me it is not acceptable, because I need to use delay.

```
init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getUser()
        }
    }

// before

    private fun getUser() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepository.getUser().collectLatest { userModel ->
                homeState.update {
                    copy(
                        userModel = userModel,
                        nameAndSurname = userModel?.nameAndSurname ?: "",
                        number = userModel?.phoneNumber ?: "",
                        email = userModel?.email ?: "",
                        registrationNumber = userModel?.registrationNumber ?: "",
                        emailTo = userModel?.emailTo ?: "",
                        emailFrom = userModel?.emailFrom ?: ""
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

// after
    private fun getUser() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepository.getUser().filterNotNull().collectLatest { userModel ->
                homeState.update {
                    copy(
                        userModel = userModel,
                        nameAndSurname = userModel?.nameAndSurname ?: "",
                        number = userModel?.phoneNumber ?: "",
                        email = userModel?.email ?: "",
                        registrationNumber = userModel?.registrationNumber ?: "",
                        emailTo = userModel?.emailTo ?: "",
                        emailFrom = userModel?.emailFrom ?: ""
                    )
                }
                delay(100L)
                checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
            }
        }
    }


This is because homeState.update needs a little bit time to update date.
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate#prevent

Comment: it didn't help please read edit post

Comment: Hey, can  you post the viewmodel code? I may be able to propose a solution using `runBlocking {}`

Comment: you can follow this medium documentation. I did and I applied splash screen to my project. https://developersancho.medium.com/jetpack-compose-splash-screen-api-36ca40c6196b

Answer (score 1):

I will show you my implementation in order to get an idea of how I did this. It works with any Android version I tested. Keep in mind that you should see it in an actual device and not in Android Studio because sometimes you have problems!

**Implementation**

```
//Splash Screen
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    .
    .
    .


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        vmProfile.checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()

        val content: View = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
        content.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
            object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
                override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                    return if (!vmProfile.isLoading.value) {
                        content.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                        true
                    } else false
                }
            }
        )

        setContent {

                  .
                  .
                  .
```

Then apply your logic in `viewModel` and observe the value

**View Model**

```
private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

fun checkIfUserIsLoggedIn() {
   .
   .
   .
   _isLoading.value = false
}
```

Comment: The user asked for a solution related to jetpack compose.

Comment: @Michael Before you downvote read first. I have successfully used it in my jetpack compose app before `setContent{`